# JAVA Swing - Update UI (breaks until I move it around)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Im pretty new to SWING and I tried my best but this is what is happening.

I have a interface that looks like this:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17524455/nodelete/1.jpg

**From the main thread I call:**

```
FrmMain.settextParticipants(5 + "");
FrmMain.setLaps(5 + "");
FrmMain.setRaceType("standard");
```

**And that goes OK.**

*I Even manage to update the stoptime and time in the upper part of the GUI.*

**But as soon as I call (in the next line)**

> PnlRacers.PnlTransparents[0].setNameAndKartNr("01", "RACER");

My UI breaks like this:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17524455/nodelete/2.jpg

And the only thing that helps to fix the UI is, when I grab the **window and move it around** (to my second screen for example). That tells me that the "data" or "functions" are working well I guess... But the REDRAWING (or how to call it) is somehow ok for the first arguments and broken for the last class. After moving around it looks like this: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17524455/nodelete/3.jpg

I read something about *redraw()* and *validate()* and I tried all on all places and on any element I was working with :(.

Maybe someone knows what the problem could be and if the source should be any help, here it is: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17524455/nodelete/TEST.rar

Please help :) Im so lost ...

Comment: ..failing to call the `super` paint method?  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: I was about to post your image until I realized you have enough rep to do it yourself.

Comment: BTW - you offer the source as an *archive that comes to **186KB***?!?  Who exactly do you expect to go wading through that mammoth code base looking for an error?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921009/swing-how-to-properly-update-the-ui?rq=1

Comment: Hi, sadly :-( this is my minimal code. Its only the ui and smallest code co tall it. I did remove all the unnecessary code. Its just ui. + background image and fonts. So the size of the archive is not important. Peeskiller what do you mean by post a image? What can I do by myself please? And no I truly do not ask anyone to check all my code :-) just maybe to confirm if what they think is possible. Plus

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried calling repaint() to the content pane after the change you implemented?

Comment: repaint() is what I was missing!! :) thank you!